# How to copy a directory from smb server to linux?

Tags: linux, bash, smb

I'm trying to copy a directory from an smb link `smb://source/path` to a Linux machine

I have tried

```
rsync -av //source/path /destination/path
```

and

```
rsync -av smb://source/path /destination/path
```

but I get a "No such file or directory" error

Any suggestion on how to perform this task?

Comment: not sure `rsync` accept samba share, but try adding a trailling slah to directories.

Comment: can you mount the share?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `rsync` cannot directly access Windows SMB fileshares. You will need something that can communicate using the `SMB protocol`.

With [`smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html), I believe you will want to do something like this:

```
smbclient //source/path -c 'lcd /destination/path ; recurse; mget *'
```

Or you could use `mount.cifs` if you have it:

```
mkdir /source_path
mount.cifs //source/path /source_path -o user=windowsuser
rsync -av /source_path /destination/path
```

Of course, after successful mounting, you will be able to access `/source_path` as if it was a local path, so you could use `cp -a` to perform the copy also.

Alternatively, you might install [DeltaCopy Server](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) on the Windows system: it will provide a `rsync`-compatible server on the Windows side, and then you will be able to use `rsync` like this:

```
rsync -av windowsuser@source::path /destination/path
```

Note that in this case, the `path` at the source is based on a "virtual directory definition" configured at the DeltaCopy Server, and has nothing to do with Windows SMB shares.

Comment: unfortunately, The system I use doesn't have smbclinet

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`an smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html), which ships with Samba:

```
smbclient //source/path -c 'cd c:/destination/path ; put local-file'
```

The client machine, in this case is acting as a server. It needs to have a folder or drive shared via SMB for this to work.

Comment: unfortunately, The system I use doesn't have smbclinet. Is there is any python script that might do it?

Comment: Please check this link. It might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422047/copying-files-from-smb-server-to-local-drivelinux-windows-in-python